# Overlapping Drawable animation

Tags: android, drawable, android-imageview

I'm trying to make frame animation in ImageView on click. But ImageView's Image ovelaps this animation.what could be the problem? and `setimagerresource(0)` doesn't work. here is the code:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.reloadanim);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) v.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();

    }
});
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/reload"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Without this line `android:src="@drawable/reload"` animation can't be seen at all

animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spin_refresh"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/reload1"
        android:duration="400"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/reload2"
        android:duration="400"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/reload3"
        android:duration="400"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/reload"
        android:duration="400"/>

</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your code with mine. The animation will be added to an ImageView and then animated when you touch the screen.

MainActivity.java

```
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.reload);
  frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    frameAnimation.start();
    return true;
  }
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

reload.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/reload1"
    android:duration="400"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/reload2"
    android:duration="400"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/reload3"
    android:duration="400"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/reload"
    android:duration="400"/>
</animation-list>
```